# SSH Permission denied for Mininet run in VMvare Workstation

Tags: ssh, mininet

I am new to SDN as well and was trying to learn Mininet. I have installed ubuntu 18.04 in VMware Workstation and run Mininet in it by 'apt-get install'. When I try to connect Mininet from my local host, I run the following comamnd :

```
ssh -X mininet@ubuntu 18.04's ip
```

I entered mininet as passwd but denied. I've tried to modify /etc/ssh/sshd_config and restart my ssh server, but it did'nt work.
I've modified the following 3 items:

1.PermitRootLogin yes

2.PasswordAuthentication yes

3.UseLogin yes

I also have tried:
    sudo ssh -p 3022 mininet@my_ip
and could'nt connect.

Comment: Are you 100% sure the password is correct? Check it again.

Comment: Thanks for your answering. I heard that the default mininet passwd is mininet. Isn't it?